# Math class in multithreading gives errors

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, xamarin.android

I am using such code in multithreading:

Old example:

```
  class All
     {
        object lockAll = new object();
        public All ()
        {
           lock(lockAll)
           {
               double res= Magnitude(1d, 0.1d , 0.2d);
           }
        }
        private double Magnitude(double X, double Y, double Z)
        {
           return Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z);
        }
     }
```

But i see that sometimes res  is 1.3  * 10 ^-314. Why??? All is locked.:
Part of real code:

```
class PointSensors : IDisposable
    {
object lockAcs = new object(); //Can it be non static? I think yes
object lockMag = new object();
// When i got info from sensors. Multitheading method called many times every time in new thread
 public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent ev)
        {
            Sensor curS = ev.Sensor;
            long timeStamp = ev.Timestamp;
              // Vector from sensors
             Vector3 vector = new Vector3(ev.Values[0], ev.Values[1], ev.Values[2]);
                if (curS.Type == SensorType.Accelerometer)
                {
                    lock (lockAcs)
                    {
                       double TotalAcseleration = vector.Magnitude - 9.8d;
                       ...
                    }
                }

                if (curS.Type == SensorType.MagneticField))
                {
                    lock (lockMag)
                    {
                       double TotalMagVect = vector.Magnitude ;
                       ...
                    }
                }


        }
}
```

And sometimes Math functions give crazy results.

Comment: Why does this need a lock?

Comment: @Matthew - beat me by seconds :)

Comment: Could you post a test case? What multi threaded approach do you use?

Comment: Something else is going on. Static methods of `Math` are thread safe (all BCL static methods are unless documented otherwise), and that result will not come from that calculation.

Comment: .NET Math class sometimes gives errors when it is used in multitheading. The same function in Java.Math in the same code didn't give the errors. I find such things on Math.Round and Math.Sqrt... others is ok. Maybe it because my non static lock... I will try to post case if i can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your lock doesn't make sense since `res` is not a shared variable.  Its scope only exists within the lock so no other thread will have access to it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Because you lock on different instances. Make your lock static.

```
class All
 {
    private static object lockAll = new object();
    public All ()
    {
       lock(lockAll)
       {
           double res= Magnitude(1d, 0.1d , 0.2d);
       }
    }
    private double Magnitude(double X, double Y, double Z)
    {
       return Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z);
    }
 }
```

Comment: there is nothing in the code suggesting a need for a lock. further complicating things (now you cannot instantiate 2 `All` s) won't help him...

Comment: @TDaver You can instantiate multiple `All` instances in this A: not just concurrently (`Monitor`s are unlocked on leaving a `lock` statement).

Comment: @Richard sorry, that's what I meant to write :)

Comment: Please. See my updated post. There is always initialized instance of the class. So -static- isn't necessarily i guess.

Comment: @user1451579 I am not really sure why you get incorrect numbers. One thing I would do is make the locking object static - therefore there is going to be only one instance in AppDomain on which you would lock. Next thing to test is your devices, sometimes they can send strange data, I would try to test those devices somehow.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the problem is solved by making lock static. So every time the new instance of class is created... And its looks like System.Math class static methods isn't always thead safe. And Java.Math thread safe... may be only in Monodroid